# False negatives during array traversal

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that gets ID numbers from names:

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("
SELECT P_ID 
  FROM personal  
 WHERE personal.FirstName=:firstname 
   AND personal.LastName=:lastname 
");
```

But the names are sent to me in a spreadsheet so I need to check them against what's actually in the DB.

I import the names thus:

```
$firstnames = file("firstnames.txt");
$lastnames = file("lastnames.txt");
```

I check them like this:

```
// Identify incorrect last names
    if ($stmt1->rowCount() > 0) {
            $check = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $row = $check['lastname'];
            // Nothing to do if last name already exists
          } 
      else {
    echo "The name ".$lastnames[$i]." is not in the DB.";
       }


// Identify incorrect first names
    if ($stmt1->rowCount() > 0) {
            $check = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $row = $check['firstname'];
            // Nothing to do if first name already exists
        } 
      else 
       {
    echo "The name ".$firstnames[$i]." is not in the DB.";
       }
```

If a last name is incorrect, the corresponding FIRST name is ALSO flagged.
Similarly, if a first name is incorrect, the corresponding LAST name is ALSO flagged.

Here's sample input data:

```
Jim 
Jack 
Paul 
Rob
--------------
Smith
Jones
Aznar
Diaz
```

Let's say it's actually "Azanar" in the DB. I get messages saying 'Aznar isn't in the DB' **and** 'Paul isn't in the DB'. Whereas "Paul" is actually correct, so shouldn't be flagged.

Comment: Does this question actually make sense to you?

Comment: Yes. Are you having trouble with it?

Comment: So, I guess you want to change AND to OR?

Comment: That doesn't work. I actually ran it. Your idea will return all the Pauls, Daves etc, with surnames that aren't in the spreadsheet data I'm using. I want FirstName and LastName combos.

Comment: You just said that you wanted, firstnames returned regardless of whether or not lastnames matched (and vice versa).

Comment: No, I didn't. I **don't want** to know if there's a Paul in the DB. I want to know if there's a **Paul Aznar**. I can get the false "Aznar" flagged, but my error reporting also tells me the name Paul isn't in the DB - which is untrue.

Comment: So, maybe you want to put one `if` routine inside the other? `if firstname exists, check if lastname exists`?

Comment: That's the kind of thing I need. I've tried a couple of things but I can't get them to work with the $row = $check[] syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your prepared statement. You are querying specifically for records where both the first AND the last name match with what you provide. I think easiest would be to have two queries, first one checks the first name, second one checks the last name.

Comment: But there will be lots of Pauls and Daves and Marias. I only want to check any FirstName Paul that is linked to LastName Aznar.

Comment: If the last name Aznar isn't in the database, like you mention in your example, there is no way for your application to know which paul you're looking for. You can either say 'yes, there are some Pauls' or 'there is no Paul Aznar'. If you want to specifically find the 'Paul Azanar' record and no other Pauls then you should write or find some code that checks for common misspellings.